# Are if-then-else statements slower in TI-Basic?

Tags: performance, basic, micro-optimization, texas-instruments, ti-basic

When coding on a *very* slow machine, such as a TI-89, every statement counts.

I am often indecisive between two ways of writing if statements:

```
If bool Then
    int = 0
Else
    int = 1
End
```

or

```
int = 1
If bool Then
    int = 0
End
```

<sup>(Yes, I know with this example it doesn't really matter)</sup>

So the question is, which one is faster and why?

Comment: BENCHMARK sigh....... can avoid the branch using an XOR ....

Comment: If only there were some method we could use to find this out. I think, were I to invent it, I might call it "benchmarking". :-)

Comment: Usually the later is better because affecting a value to a variable is a lot faster than two potential jumps. "Branching is bad for performance". Now, it really depends on how the language works. A TI-89 certainly uses a very slow interpreter, in which case, the less characters the better.

Comment: @MitchWheat I'm also curious about the _why_

Comment: The TI-89 uses a Motorola 68k. GCC can compile into 68k. I never tested for this particular architecture, but I am willing to bet that writing C code and having the compiler worry about optimization is faster than TI-BASIC. Also you get to write in C :-)

Comment: Yeah, @FirefoxMetzger , there is actually a program called TIGCC for that! I do use it, but there are occasions when I need on-calc programming.

Answer (score 1):

For TI-89 Basic, use `when`: `when(bool,0,1)`.